# Prove that Two Angles Are Congruent in a Right Triangle

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, plane-geometry

In a right triangle $ABC$ with $\angle ACB$ the right angle, point $D$ is on the side $\overline{AB}$. Segment $\overline{BE}$ is perpendicular to $\overline{CD}$ and intersects $\overline{CD}$ at point $E$. Point $F$ is on $\overline{DE}$ such that $CE=EF$. Segment $\overline{FG}$ is perpendicular to $\overline{CD}$ and intersects $\overline{BD}$ at $G$.

Prove that $m\angle AFD=m\angle BCG$.

[image]

I am not familiar with results beyond geometry taught in high school. Maybe some ingenious auxiliary line can be drawn to solve the problem beautifully, but I cannot come up with any good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $X$ as the reflection of $F$ over the line $AB$. By Thales' theorem, we see that the quadrilateral $DFGX$ is cyclic. We can also see that $\overline{BC}=\overline{BF}=\overline{BX}$. It follows that $B$ is the circumcentre of the triangle $CFX$. Because $AC\perp BC$, the line $AC$ is tangent to this circle.

Now we see that $$\angle XGA=\angle XFD=\angle XCA,$$ where the second equality follows from $AC$ being tangent to the circle $CFX$. This means that the quadrilateral $ACGX$ is cyclic.

We finish the proof by noting that $$\angle GCB=\frac{\pi}{2}-\angle ACG=\frac{\pi}{2}-\pi+\angle GXA=\angle AFG-\frac{\pi}{2}=\angle AFD.$$

**Remark:** *$ACGX$ being cyclic is a special case of Miquel's theorem for triangle $ADC$ and points $G$, $F$ and $C$.*
[image: Diagram]

Comment: A typo: B is the circumcenter of triangle CFX (not DFX). Why $\angle XFD=\angle XCA$? AC is a tangent of circle B, and the measure of $\angle ACX$ is one half the measure of arc XFC, but $\angle XFD$ is inscribed in another circle. Maybe I missed some important steps here.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it. The angle $\angle ACX$ is equal to the inscribed angle of the arc $XC$. $\angle XFC$ is $\pi$ minus that angle, because it's on the other side of the line $CX$, so we get $\angle ACX=\pi-\angle XFC=\angle DFX$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Note that $\angle ACD = \angle CBE = 90- \angle ECB = \theta$. Apply the sine rule to the triangles ACF and BCG, respectively,

$$\frac{\sin(\alpha - \theta)}{\sin\alpha} = \frac{2a\sin\theta}b=2\cot\beta\sin\theta \\
\frac{\sin(\gamma + \beta)}{\sin\gamma} = \frac a{\frac{a\sin\theta}{\sin(\beta-\theta)}}
=\frac{\sin(\beta-\theta)}{\sin\theta}
$$
Simplify the two equations to get

\begin{align}
& \cos\theta -\cot\alpha \sin\theta = 2\cot\beta\sin\theta \\
& \cos\beta+\cot\gamma\sin\beta= \sin\beta \cot \theta-\cos\beta
\end{align}

which lead to

$$\cot\alpha = \cot\gamma = \cot\theta - 2\cot\beta$$

i.e, $\angle AFD= \angle BCG$.